# Umbraco 4.0 install "database initialization failed"

Tags: database, umbraco, ssms

I am trying to st up a local instance of Umbraco using SQL Express. I know this procedure backwards in terms of setting up the site, creating the database and editing the webconfig file.

Manage get to stage three of setting up Umbraco 4.0 and it loads to 5% then I get this error:

"Database initialization failed"

I have mixed authentication turned on within SQL, triple checked my database path within the webconfig and still cannot get it to connect.

It seems as though Umbraco is having trouble connecting to the server but really with things like this it could be anything.

All suggestions welcome!

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, and belongs on serverfault.com or superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your connection string look like? If it is the default instance of SQL Express make sure the connection string's data source is referencing the instance name. Try.\SQLEXPRESS or localhost\SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=test.co.nz;user id=test_usr;password=password

It was exactly as you have it there ".\SQLEXPRESS" I haven't tried localhost\ yet so will give that a go and let you know - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After lot of searching through various forums , i am thinking it could be due to the lack of write permissions to the web.config file and the rest of files. Because the user is going to choose a lot of values at install time the installer must make changes to the web.config file. But if you see the permissions for the entire folder structure its READ ONLY.

I'm stuck here.. Cannot change the read-only permission to write..

any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error we need to change **umbracoDbDSN** value.

---

When we try to install Umbraco, can get following error "Database connection initialisation failed."

This error shows that Sql server is not connecting. If you have right credentials then just add those in Web.Config of Umbraco.

```
<add key="umbracoDbDSN" value="server=ServerName;database=UmbracoDB;user id=sa;password=YourPassword" />
```

Enter value of umbracoDbDSN

Now Database will install successfully.

---

Solution resource: http://xpode.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ArticleId=608

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for database initialization 5% struck issue.

Try to run solution within Chrome browser from WebMatrix.

After struggling many hours, tryingout all the below:

1) Make the Umbraco folder IIS_users - read/write/modify permissions
2) Make the database user - DBOwner/DBWriter/DBReader

When the problem still persisted, I opened the Umbraco site in Chrome(instead of IE9) and realized that it completed database initialization.

Good Luck..Bhaskar